# How to delete on-demand files on onedrive for mac without having to download them first?

Tags: macos, finder, microsoft

If I delete a file from onedrive for mac with files on-demand turned on and that file has not downloaded to my computer, it has to first download it and then move it to trash. This is rather annoying and a behavior that does not exist on onedrive windows or ios version.

1. **How can I just delete that file from the remote server without having to download it on my hard drive first?**
2. Is this a bug or a designed behavior of Microsoft? Or the apple finder extension api just does not support this?
3. Dose similar issue exist on Google Drive or Dropbox app for mac?